# How to use RazorGenerator in project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview, razorgenerator

I want to use RazorGenerator for partial views between project in MVC. I have searched many websites but I can't find it anywhere. I have added the NuGet package to my project and after what am I doing?
Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You need to do the following:

- Go to an MVC Razor view's property and set the Custom tool to
  RazorGenerator
- Optionally specify a value for Custom Tool Namespace to specify a
  namespace for the generated file. The project namespace is used by
  default.
- Optionally specify one of the generators in the first line of your
  Razor file. A generator declaration line looks like this: @*
  Generator: MvcHelper *@ . If you don't specify this, a generator is
  picked based on convention (e.g. files under Views are treated as
  MvcViews)
- You'll see a generated .cs file under the .cshtml file, which will be
  used at runtime instead of the .cshtml file
- You can also go to the nuget Package Manager Console and run
  'Enable-RazorGenerator' to enable the Custom Tool on all the views.
- And to cause all the views to be regenerated, go to the nuget Package
  Manager Console and run 'Redo-RazorGenerator'. This is useful when
  you update the generator package and it needs to generate different
  code.

More can be found at [Razor Generator](https://github.com/RazorGenerator/RazorGenerator)

Comment: Thank you .İ want to know am ı use this with .net framework ? probably it is use only class library.

Comment: yes, it works with .Net Framework. I've not tried with .Net Core, but probably not...someone may correct me on this

Comment: Actually i want to use partial view beetwen 2 .net project in same solition   what do you think about ? razorgenerate can help me? or can you advice another way please?

Comment: You would need to reference RazorGenerator in both projects, then it should be ok.

Comment: if ı dont use razorgenerator , can ı do this other way?

Comment: I dont know of any other product that will pre-compile your razor. There probably are other products out there though. In all instances though I'd think you'd still have to reference the library, otherwise when you try to build/compile the project, how will VS know what to do if it hasn't got the references.

Comment: already i give referance but probably referance is not enough for call partial view. cant find page. i call partial view other project but vs search in only the page belongs to project.it dont look reference:/